# PXE boot Linux - which directories must be writable?

Tags: linux, pxe-boot, hadoop

I'm planning to set up a small Hadoop cluster where the slave nodes boot and run from a central PXE server, to simplify deployment and updates, and to enable all of the disks on the slaves to be (almost) monopolized by HDFS.

However, I suppose I'll still have to reserve some space on the slave nodes for /tmp and /var/log, I don't want to just put these in a ramdisk because I'd like them there for debugging after crashes (and because RAM is scarcer than disk).

So the machines might boot off the remote PXE server, mount their / read-only from there, then mount /dev/sda1 through sdd1 for the HDFS data partitions, /dev/sda2 for /tmp, and /dev/sdb2 for /var/log.

My question is, are there any other directories that will need to be writable? Assuming we get Hadoop etc. to log into /var/log.

(And is this a sensible architecture in general?)

EDIT: don't worry about swap, I'm planning to make these swapless, the OOM killer is preferable to thrashing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can study livecd layout of your distro, but likely you need /var instead of /var/log and in some distros there are files in /etc that must be writable. /home as well unless you put home dir elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think of reverse-engineering a live CD.

Answer (score 1):

"(And is this a sensible architecture in general?)...."

I wouldn't say that your idea is wrong but seems interesting. In a nutshell your setting up a diskless architecture but still using the localdisk. To me your adding extra loops.

"to simplify deployment and updates .. "

If your goal is to make it more centralized and manageable. I would use some sort of automated distribution engine.  Like in my case, I use puppet. The code is already available on github. Just customize to your needs. That should take care of your simplification & manageability.  I built couple of clusters in no time using my puppet manifests.

Comment: I have accepted the other one because it was a more direct answer, but have upvoted yours as well because it has got me thinking. Perhaps Puppet is a better idea after all. 

My motivation was to reduce the usage of the local disks as well, though, to maximize the amount of storage and I/O that HDFS can use. So I'm still not sure.

Comment: Andrew, thank you for the vote. I am little curious on the performance impact for not using local disks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution for Slackware 14.2 (BSD init, not systemd) booting via PXE with the root filesystem served read-only over NFS.

I simply modified `/etc/rc.d/rc.S` to copy the folders that need to be writable (`/etc` and `/var`) into a tmpfs filesystem, mount temporary filesystems over the original folders, and move the copies into the temporary filesystems:

```
# Copy /etc and /var as tmpfs prior to starting any processes.
echo "Creating volatile copies of /etc and /var in memory..."
mount -t tmpfs -o size=256m tmpfs /tmp
cp -a /etc /tmp/etc
mount -t tmpfs -o size=16m tmpfs /etc
mv /tmp/etc/* /etc/
rmdir /tmp/etc
cp -a /var /tmp/var
mount -t tmpfs -o size=16m tmpfs /var
mv /tmp/var/* /var/
rmdir /tmp/var
```

The above was inserted at the top of `rc.S`, preceded only by the line that sets the `PATH` variable. This runs at the very start of init, prior to any other partitions being mounted or services starting.

Any changes to these in-memory copies are simply discarded on reboot.